# What is the difference between "faire" and "jouer"?

Tags: grammaire

Could you please tell me what is the differnce between these 2 sentences:
Je fais du tennis.
Je joue au tennis.

Je fais du piano.
Je joue du piano.

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que l’on dit "**jouer** au tennis" pour mettre l'accent plutôt sur l'aspect jeu/divertissement du sport, alors qu’en disant "**faire** du tennis", l'accent serait plutôt sur son côté professionnel.

Il en serait de même pour le piano; si vous dites "je joue du piano", vous exprimez votre capacité ou votre action. Par contre lorsque vous dites "je fais du piano", vous affirmez que vous êtes un professionnel,  que vous ne le faites pas que pour le plaisir.
(NB que le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle, mais c'est ce que je comprends par ces deux expressions.)

Comment: The text of your answer has been corrected as far as is possible; it remains  the little bit "et que l'on fait accent", which is a dangling element in the sentence and which, moreover, can't be made out.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially equivalent.

I would say that sentences using "faire" are a bit more familiar, because "faire" can be used to replace **a lot** of verbs. In my opinion, using "faire" instead of an other verb which would be more descriptive, basically shows a lesser intent to formulate precisely what you are trying to say because "it's good enough" in the context of its use.

In the words of Todd Howard, "it just works".

Answer (score 0):

Most of us would never notice the difference in everyday life. This is the exact same thing.

However, if you would like the complex answer, [this](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/076.html) could help you. Basically, "faire" is here *un verbe transitif indirect*.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

« faire » dans la langue française est ce qui a été appelé par le passé, tout au moins dans certains milieux de l'enseignement du français, un verbe à tout faire; c'est le verbe à tout faire par excellence. « Il fait du piano. » ? On peut comprendre par cela « Il est en train de s'exercer au piano. », c'est sujet au contexte; dans ce cas il n'est pas question d'un professionnel du piano mais d'un étudiant. « faire », dans une multitude d'usages de cette sorte est la marque d'un français que les oreilles tant soit peu exigeantes ne trouvent pas très bon mais à peine acceptable, et il vaut mieux l'éviter; « jouer » est préférable, et si on ne peut pas non plus, sans contexte, savoir ce qui est dit, c'est au moins un mot spécifique; « jouer du piano » peut signifier trois choses: soit « **jouer sur l'instrument** », quel que soit le niveau (exercice, répétition ou performance), soit « **être un musicien professionnel** », soit « **savoir jouer du piano** ».

> - Qu'est-ce qu'il fait ? Il joue du piano dans le salon.
> - Comment gagne-t-il sa vie ? Il joue du piano dans un bar.
> - Il joue du piano mais sa famille n'aime pas sa musique.

Dans le contexte de l'activité d'un professionnel du piano on ne devrait jamais dire « il/elle fait du piano. »; on peut utiliser « faire » à la limite dans le contexte de l'activité qui consiste à s'exercer quand l'exercice est simple, quand il s'agit de la période de formation en d'autres mots; lorsqu'il s'agit d'un artiste qui se joue à lui-même des morceaux complets ou non pour soigner son interprétation on utilise fondamentalement le verbe « répéter ».

Answer (score 0):

Faire du tennis would be more of an occupation, a long-term, possibly verging on the professional, obsessive occupation.  Jouer au tennis, while it could be used in exactly the same way, could also be more likely to be an afternoon's entertainment by someone who does know how to do it, but possibly vaguely.

But also faire is definitely more informal than jouer, so that might be a more important factor in deciding which to use.